# devexpress scheduler - get resourceId when select cell on same row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

i have some problem with component Scheduler.
I have calendare, where i have resource on left side and date on top. So i want get resourceid when i select some cell on same row.

I try it solve over

```
function OnSelectionChanged(s,e)
{
    s.GetSelectedFieldValues("ResourceID", GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback);
}
```

, but i cant get resourceid, or column index.

Here is image what i think.
[image]
<sub>(source: [jpeg.cz](http://www.jpeg.cz/images/2014/11/22/bm0r.png))</sub>

Thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cshtml file:

```
scheduler.ClientSideEvents.SelectionChanged = "OnDispatcherSchedulerItemChanged";
```

In JavaScript code:

```
function OnDispatcherSchedulerItemChanged(s, e) {
      alert(s.selection.resource);
}
```